# jQuery - Making new div on interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this, setinterval

So what I'm trying to do here is make a page that spawns a new random color and size box every 2 seconds, that are removed when I click on them. The problem is, the first box gets created with no problem, but after that, I get the error that my function "makeDiv" is not defined every 2 seconds.

Am I missing something?

```
setInterval('makeDiv', 2000);

(function makeDiv() {
    var divsize = ((Math.random() * 100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width': divsize + 'px',
        'height': divsize + 'px',
        'background-color': color
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px',
        'display': 'none'
    }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(100)

    $("div").click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

})();
```

Comment: move it outside the self executing function

Comment: `setInterval` executes function in window scope after first call; That's why you need to move the `makeDiv` outside the IIFE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is .. you used makeDiv in setinterval as a function but you use it in `(function(){});` and its looks like its in `$(document).ready()` so it just worked for the first time .. it worked itself after document ready  not working in setinterval  .. so what I did here is just make a clear function .. with  `function makeDiv(){}`  not `(function makeDiv(){}());`  and about

```
$(document).on('click' , 'div',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

I prefer to use the code one time not repeat it with every setInterval so I used this code outside the function instead of use it inside like

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click' , 'div',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

setInterval('makeDiv()', 2000);

function makeDiv() {
    var divsize = ((Math.random() * 100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width': divsize + 'px',
        'height': divsize + 'px',
        'background-color': color
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px',
        'display': 'none'
    }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(100);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update Demo with animation**

```js
$(document).on('click' , 'div',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

setInterval('makeDiv()', 2000);

function makeDiv() {
    var divsize = ((Math.random() * 100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width': divsize + 'px',
        'height': divsize + 'px',
        'background-color': color
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px',
        'display': 'none'
    }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(100).animate({'left' : '0px', 'right': $(window).width() - divsize} , 3000).animate({'right' : '0px', 'left': $(window).width() - divsize} , 3000);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you add a bit of explanation. i am also confused when it comes to making function like this. i can determine the scope of function. if you can add explanation that would help

Comment: can you add why it didnt work and what you did so it works?sorry for asking for more explanation

Comment: @guradio I updated my answer and explain everything :)

Comment: this will help many readers including me :) happy coding mate

Comment: Thank you so much for this! And thanks for the cleanup advice. This answered all of my problems!

Comment: Thanks, my next task is to animate the div's to move left to right across the screen. hah!

Comment: @JHillman answer updated with animation .. is this what you want??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef That helps! I'm trying to make it move back and forth though. I tried this 
https://jsfiddle.net/q5dbtLp6/
Unsuccessful so far. I think I'm missing something simple. (Also, I haven't got the hang of jsfiddle yet so it probably doesn't work there, but the code is there. haha)

Comment: @JHillman you can play around my animate code to do what you want .. check out my updated answer

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you for all your help.  I ended up using the css transform way. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the IIFE
so I have make it as a normal function & calling

setInterval like this

```
setInterval(makeDiv, 2000);
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/01e8oLsv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the ideal ans but, this is an alternative you could try:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var divsize = ((Math.random() * 100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width': divsize + 'px',
        'height': divsize + 'px',
        'background-color': color
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px',
        'display': 'none'
    }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(100)

}, 2000);

$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```